# Loop over a QString and do a comparison each time with QChar

Tags: qt

I have a QString in which i want to search for a sign. So i tried to do this with

```
if(inLineEditDisplay[i]=="+")
```

but without success. The error i get is

```
error: conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'QChar' is ambiguous
```

What's the correct way to compare a QChar with a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're comparing one unicode character (`QChar`) with a C-style string literal (because `"+"` is actually an array of two chars, the `'+'` and the `0` byte for termination).

Use this:

```
if (inLineEditDisplay[i] == QLatin1Char('+'))
  ...
```

Comment: With that i get: `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Read the code once again and use ``'`` (apostrophe) instead of ``"`` (quote).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that there's a difference. Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: Do you know why you must use `'` here?

Comment: Because you're comparing characters, not strings. ``'`` -> charcater, ``"`` -> string. That's just how C and C++ work.